# SAS: variable not being stored in the temporary dataset?

Tags: sas

My variable is not being stored in the temporary dataset. I go to create the contingency table and it can't find the variable Avg_SF I just created.

I was expecting the variable to be found right after I created it.

here is the code and the log.

Thanks so much.

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/53VRm.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WYGrF.png)

Answer (score 2):

Your `keep` statement on the third-to-last line will remove any variables that aren't listed in it.

Answer (score 0):

If you're concerned about efficiency or just keeping things straight, you can drop your unneeded variables as part of the set statement:

```
set MyLib.dry_bean(drop=Extent AspectRatio);
```

and then add Avg_SF to your keep statement below as was previously suggested. And if you prefer writing less code you could just eliminate the drop statement altogether because by using the keep statement you're essentially telling SAS to drop everything that is not in the keep statement anyway.